# Counting items using .length on click producing incorrect value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, string-length

## Objective

- A button should be able to be selected and clicking that same button
  should then unselect that button
- When the number of buttons with the class of `is-selected === 3` change the cursor behaviour using to `pointer-events: none` unless a button is unselected first

## Problem

I have a series of buttons `btn--like` and when I unselect a button it `countLike`, which is counting the number of buttons with the class `is-selected`. The unexpected behaviour is that I click three buttons and then when I click a previously selected button to unselect it, **`countLike is 4, instead of 2`**

### scripts.js

```
$(".btn--like").on("click", function(){
    let countLike = ($(".btn--like.is-selected").length) + 1;
    console.log(countLike);

    $(this).toggleClass("is-selected");
    $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-grey");
    $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-red");

    if (countLike === 3) {
        $(".btn--like:not(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
    } else {
        $(".btn--like").css("pointer-events", "auto");
    }
});
```

### index.html

```
<div class="button__group">
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Jewelry <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Scarves <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Fishing <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Cologne <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Shirts <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Sports apparel <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to check how many have the `is-selected` class **after** toggling that class on the button that was clicked?

Comment: Note that `pointer-events: none` does nothing to prevent using the keyboard or accessibility software to press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle the class on the current button **first**, then take the `length` (see comments):

```js
$(".btn--like").on("click", function() {
  // FIRST toggle the classs
  $(this).toggleClass("is-selected");

  // THEN take the count
  let countLike = $(".btn--like.is-selected").length;
  console.log(countLike);

  $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-grey");
  $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-red");

  if (countLike === 3) {
    $(".btn--like:not(.is-selected)").css("pointer-events", "none");
  } else {
    $(".btn--like").css("pointer-events", "auto");
  }
});
```

```css
.is-selected {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="button__group">
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Jewelry <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Scarves <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Fishing <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Cologne <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Shirts <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Sports apparel <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

FWIW, I'd probably also actually change the `disabled` state of the buttons rather than just disabling pointer events on them:

```js
$(".btn--like").on("click", function() {
  // FIRST toggle the class
  $(this).toggleClass("is-selected");

  // THEN take the count
  let countLike = $(".btn--like.is-selected").length;
  console.log(countLike);

  $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-grey");
  $(this).children(".fa-check").toggleClass("is-red");

  // Update the disabled property rather than using pointer-events
  if (countLike === 3) {
    $(".btn--like:not(.is-selected)").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".btn--like").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```css
.is-selected {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="button__group">
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Jewelry <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Scarves <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Fishing <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Cologne <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Shirts <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn--option btn--like">Sports apparel <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the countLike regardless of whether the button was selected or unselected.

Try this:

```
let countLike = ($(".btn--like.is-selected").length);

if ($(this).hasClass("is-selected")) {
    countLike += 1;
} else {
    countLike -= 1;
}
```

Alternatively, do the toggle first, and then simply count the number of elements with the required selector, instead of increasing/decreasing the count yourself:

```
$(this).toggleClass("is-selected");
let countLike = ($(".btn--like.is-selected").length);
```

This will automatically do +1 or -1 depending on the toggle.